How can I get a current year vs prior year comparison in dax using selectedvalue and a month and year slicer?
The measure I created works fine for current year no matter what year and month I select. However, the prior year measure has missing values in some locations. The values should be there because they are in the dataset and when I adjust the slicers to the prior year it populates using the current year measure.
May 2023 wont populate all locations using prior year measure.
If I adjust the slicers to May 2023 everything shows.
Current Year Measure
MTDNetRevenue_CY =
VAR _CurrentPeriod = SELECTEDVALUE( DIMDate[month_number] )
VAR _CurrentYear = SELECTEDVALUE( DIMDate[year] )
VAR _Result =
CALCULATE(
SUM(NetIncome[NetRevenue]),
FILTER( ALL( DIMDate ),
DIMDate[month_number] = _CurrentPeriod &&
DIMDate[year] = _CurrentYear),
NetIncome[Type]="MTD")
RETURN
IF( HASONEVALUE(DIMDate[month_number]) , _Result ,
CALCULATE(SUM(NetIncome[NetRevenue]), FILTER( ALL( DIMDate ),DIMDate[month_number] = _CurrentPeriod && DIMDate[year] = _CurrentYear),NetIncome[Type]="MTD"))
Prior Year Measure
MTDNetRevenue_PY =
VAR _CurrentPeriod = SELECTEDVALUE( DIMDate[month_number] )
VAR _CurrentYear = SELECTEDVALUE( DIMDate[year] )-1
VAR _Result =
CALCULATE(
SUM(NetIncome[NetRevenue]),
FILTER( ALL( DIMDate ),
DIMDate[month_number] = _CurrentPeriod &&
DIMDate[year] = _CurrentYear),
NetIncome[Type]="MTD")
RETURN
--_Result
IF( HASONEVALUE(DIMDate[month_number]) , _Result ,
CALCULATE(SUM(NetIncome[NetRevenue]), FILTER( ALL( DIMDate ),DIMDate[month_number] = _CurrentPeriod && DIMDate[year] = _CurrentYear),NetIncome[Type]="MTD"))
I'm checked the relationship but that did not fix the problem. I'm expecting prior year data to show in the table just as it does in the current year table when the slicers are adjusted to that period.
UPDATE: The tables are showing values for the current month are blank. Is there a work around so that the prior year info still shows?
